# Publish IOS app (capacitor) using Codemagic

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, apple-developer, codemagic

I have a Vue Capacitor app. I'm trying to publish an iOS app, and for that, I'm using Codemagic for publishing an iOS app, and I'm facing issues while publishing an iOS app in [Codemagic](https://codemagic.io). It is not able to progress beyond this step.
[image]

This is my codemagic.yaml that triggers build steps, and I'm facing an issue on the step "- name: Build ipa for distribution".

```
workflows:
  ionic-capacitor-ios-workflow:
    name: Ionic Capacitor iOS Workflow
    max_build_duration: 120
    instance_type: mac_mini_m1
    integrations:
      app_store_connect: Codemagic API Key
    environment:
      ios_signing:
        # distribution_type: app_store
        bundle_identifier: org.hireaspy.app
        provisioning_profiles:
          - codemagic_provisioning_profiles
        certificates:
          - Development_Certificate
      vars:
        # Ionic Xcode worskspace and scheme
        XCODE_WORKSPACE: "ios/App/App.xcworkspace"
        XCODE_SCHEME: "App"
        APP_STORE_APP_ID: 6456386785 # <-- Put the app id number here. This is found in App Store Connect > App > General > App Information
      node: 16.15.1
      xcode: latest
      cocoapods: 1.12.1
    triggering:
      events:
        - push
      branch_patterns:
        - pattern: develop
          include: true
          source: true
    scripts:
      - name: Install npm dependencies for Ionic project
        script: |
          npm install
      - name: Cocoapods installation
        script: |
          cd ios/App && pod install
      - name: Update dependencies and copy web assets to native project
        script: |
          npx cap sync ios # <- update native dependencies and copy web assets to native project
          npx cap copy ios # <- use this is you don't need to update native dependencies
      - name: Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
        script: |
          xcode-project use-profiles
      - name: Increment build number
        script: |
          cd $CM_BUILD_DIR/ios/App
          LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER=$(app-store-connect get-latest-app-store-build-number "$APP_ID")
          agvtool new-version -all $(($LATEST_BUILD_NUMBER + 1))
      - name: Build ipa for distribution
        script: |
          xcode-project build-ipa \
            --workspace "$CM_BUILD_DIR/$XCODE_WORKSPACE" \
            --scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME"
    artifacts:
      - build/ios/ipa/*.ipa
      - /tmp/xcodebuild_logs/*.log
      - $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**/Build/**/*.app
      - $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**/Build/**/*.dSYM
    publishing:
      email:
        recipients:
          - john.doe@gmail.com
        notify:
          success: false     # To not receive a notification when a build succeeds
          failure: false     # To not receive a notification when a build fails
      app_store_connect:
        auth: integration

        # Configuration related to TestFlight (optional)
        # Note: This action is performed during post-processing.
        submit_to_testflight: true
        # beta_groups: # Specify the names of beta tester groups that will get access to the build once it has passed beta review.
          # - group name 1
          # - group name 2

        # Configuration related to App Store (optional)
        # Note: This action is performed during post-processing.
        submit_to_app_store: false
```

Comment: hi! Codemagic engineer is here. Did it work before or you try to setup your first build? Can you confirm you run the same commands locally without any issues? looks like the error related to Xcode settings not Codemagic

Comment: @MikhailTokarev Yes, locally it works fine. I can't publish an app since my system is an old version.